# Binding Scope in ComponentDidMount for Radium Enhanced Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, radium

I'm working on React component called `ProjectCard` that holds two divs. The second div has a dropdown, and I want to highlight the entire card when the user hovers over the card or the dropdown has been clicked. I used Radium for adding hover functionality to previous components, but in order to incorporate this new logic for highlighting, I tracked `isActive` and `isLocked` in the card state. For example, I toggle `isActive` when mouse enters or leaves the component in the following function. (I bound `toggleActive` in the constructor)

```
toggleActive () {
  console.log(this);
  this.setState({
    isActive: !this.state.isActive
  });
}
```

However, I got an error that I could not set state before the component was mounted. Poking around a bit and logging `this` in various functions, it seemed like it was a problem with Radium. I used the Radium wrapper in my export, like so: `export default Radium(ProjectCard);`, and the above `toggleActive` logged `ProjectCard` as `this`, while `componentDidMount` logged `RadiumEnhancer(ProjectCard)` as `this`. A Radium-less workaround would be to use a HoC, but I thought I could maybe fix this by adjusting the scope I bound this, so I moved the function binding to `componentDidMount`, as shown below. (Using arrow functions automatically bound scope like calls from the constructor)

```
constructor (props: Props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isActive: true,
    isLocked: false
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this);
  this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  this.toggleLock = this.toggleLock.bind(this);
  this.toggleActive = this.toggleActive.bind(this);
  console.log("mounted, functions bound");
  //console.log(this.toggleActive);
  this.toggleActive();
  //manual fix, stackoverflow this.
}
```

However, binding in componentDidMount and hovering over the component caused no change and `toggleActive` to log `this` as undefined. No luck, the fix didn't appear to work.

However, while trying to debug, I manually invoked toggleActive (as shown above) and it logged `RadiumEnhancer(ProjectCard)` (the scope I wanted) and miraculously, hover functionality started working (and the other functions also got the correct scope).

My questions are:

- Was the improper scope/Radium causing the setState error? There were no async operations in the code other than setState.
- If so, is this fix legitimate? Why didn't it work after I changed the scope I bound `this` to?
- Why did manually calling toggleActive give all the functions the right `this` and scope?

Thank you!
Here is a pastebin for relevant code: https://pastebin.com/MRKw2APw

Comment: Try to use arrow function definition `componentDidMount = () => {}` this way `componentDidMount` will use as context `this`.

Comment: Using arrow notation defaults this to the unenhanced ProjectCard, so that doesn't work, thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

If you delete everything in your render function and just render a simple p tag, you will see 'this' and 'toggleActive' is not undefined. Double check your render function.

Comment: I reduced my render function to the following and hovering says "cannot setState of undefined" (where `this` is undefined). Leaving binding functions in componentDidMount, I get this error both with and w/o arrow notation. Render is just 
          `return ( <div style={styles.wrap} onMouseEnter={this.toggleActive} />`